# How to find the limit of this convergent sum?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^{k} D^{i}$, where $k = \frac{1}{2} n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1>D>0$. The ratio test proves that this sum converges, but I struggle finding a closed form for the limit. Any suggestions how to get there?

Answer (score 1):

The explicit expression for the sum is:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} i^{k} D^{i}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}A_i^{k}D^{i+1}}{(1-D)^{k+1}},
$$
where $A_i^k$ are the [Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number). Can be easily proved by induction.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am afraid you might have overlooked that $k$ is not a natural number, but a fraction. Does your result still hold then?

Comment: Yes I have overlooked it. Do you look for the solution only for odd $n$?

Comment: No I am afraid not, though your answer led me to look at the polylogarithmic function, and the way I see it, that might be what I am looking at

Comment: Yes the general expression for the sum is $\text{Li}_{-k}(D)$.